# What is the best way to prove this?

Tags: geometry

Consider a Cyclic Quadrilateral ABCD. The diagonals AC and BD meet
at the point P, and DA and CB produced meet at Q. The midpoint of AB is E.
Show that if PQ is perpendicular to AC, then PE is perpendicular
to BC.

Comment: do you mean midpoint of BC is E, because PE mayn't even intersect AB?